What are the logistics behind getting everyone on and off a sandworm?
In Dune: Part Two (2024), we saw how intense it was when Paul hitched a ride on a giant sandworm, clinging on for dear life. But then later, there is a scene with like dozens of Fremen casually riding a sandworm, complete with the Reverend Mother’s palanquin and her full retinue in tow.

I get how one person could mount a sandworm, but how did all those Fremen manage to get on and off together? Especially with the Reverend Mother's crew and all their gear. 
The movie didn't really show the logistics of how they pulled that off. I'd like to know the "behind-the-scenes" of that process. Getting on seems tricky enough already, but dismounting from a sandworm traveling at full speed sounds downright terrifying!
What are the logistics behind how a large group of Fremen ride a sandworm, and how do they get off? Is it even possible to put the brakes on a sandworm? Do they just… jump? What about the Reverend Mother's palanquin and her entourage?


I think it just comes down to timing- everyone hooks on to a segment at the same time.

Same as the logistics behind dismounting a dragon in Westeros: best never looked at.

It's like boarding a Southwest Airlines flight - first come, first served!

Very important not to be a "dead head" worm rider: The conductors are especially zealous when they find someone without a ticket; being tossed off a sandworm is a very serious matter indeed.

I agree with Valorum's answer, but I think it's worth commenting on the logic here. First, Paul's experience is unusual as he's a first timer and his worm is unusually large. Second, getting a first rider onto a worm is the hardest part - once the worm has a rider, they can steer it to be easier for anyone else who wants to get on (keeping it on the surface, controlling its speed and direction). Cargo and palanquins can be carried by these secondary riders. What perhaps isn't obvious in the movie is that riders don't simply hang on to uncontrolled worms, but actively steer it with their hooks.

We see a group of riders mounting a worm, complete with palanquin, in Dune: House Atreides. In short, the Fremen who captures the worm persuades it to move slowly by forcing it to the surface. This allows other riders to approach it by jogging alongside whereupon they can climb up. Finally, the non-riders are hoisted by those already on the worm. Presumably an aged Sayyadina would be carried alongside if she was incapable of running.

The worm rolled to keep its sensitive exposed segment away from the
abrasive sands. Ommun scrambled up and planted another hook, spreading
wide a second segment so that the worm was forced to rise higher out
of its secret world beneath the desert. At the highest point on the
worm’s back, behind its huge head, the young Fremen planted a stake
and dropped his long ropes so that they hung from the sides. Now he
stood tall and proud on the worm, signaling for the others to come.
Cheering, the Fremen ran forward, bringing Kynes with them. He
stumbled to keep up. Three other young men scaled the ropes, adding
more of what they called “maker hooks” to keep the worm above the
dunes. The big creature began to move forward, but in a confused
fashion, as if unable to understand why these bothersome creatures
were goading it.
As the Fremen kept pace, they tossed up supplies; packs were lashed to
the worm’s back with more ropes. The first riders assembled a small
structure as fast as they could. Prodded by Stilgar, an astonished
Kynes ran up beside the towering worm. The Planetologist could feel
friction heat rising from beneath, and he tried to imagine what
awesome chemical fires formed a furnace deep within the worm itself.
“Up you go, Umma Kynes!” Stilgar shouted, helping him place his feet
into loops in the ropes. Clumsily, Kynes scrambled up, his desert
boots finding purchase on the worm’s rough hide. He climbed and
climbed. The simmering energy of Shai-Hulud caused him to lose his
breath, but Stilgar helped him to the top where the other Fremen
riders had gathered.
They had assembled a crude platform and seat for him, a palanquin. The
other Fremen stood, holding their ropes against the enormous worm as
if it were a bucking steed. Gratefully, Kynes took the proffered seat
and held on to the arms. He had a disconcerting feeling up here, as if
he didn’t belong and could easily be toppled off and crushed to death.
The rolling movement of the worm made his stomach lurch.

They then dismount once the worm is too tired to roll over.

Finally Ommun brought the behemoth around until it ground to a halt,
exhausted. The troop of desert men dropped off while Kynes slid down
the rough worm segments onto loose sand. Ommun tossed down the
remaining packs and dismounted, letting the worm — too utterly tired to turn and attack them— wallow its way into the sands. The Fremen
removed the hooks so the worm, their Shai-Hulud, could recover.

In The Winds of Dune we see Stilgar dismounting from a worm that is still moderately energetic. He uses the classic 'tuck and roll' technique and the worm dashes off.

Exhausted after the destruction it had caused, the worm plunged toward
the arid basin. Stilgar prepared for a dangerous dismount. Thank
Shai-Hulud, he had done it many times before—and down he slid,
skillfully landing on his feet on the sand before tucking his knees,
and rolling.
After the worm had charged off into the distance, fleeing the
inhabited zone, Stilgar got to his feet again and brushed sand from
his stillsuit.

And in Dune: House Harkonnen, young Liet and his friend Warrick dismounts a sandworm by running full tilt down its length, then basically jumping off into the (relatively) powdery sand.

Warrick used his goad sticks to turn the worm closer, then they
released their hooks and made ready to dismount. Since Liet had
summoned this particular behemoth, he gestured for his friend to run
down the rough, segmented hide. “First on, last off,” Liet said.
Warrick scrambled down to the sand wake where he could leap off the
tail. He disengaged the airpack-assisted cargo cases filled with raw
melange essence and guided them beyond the monster’s reach. Warrick
leaped off and made his way to a dune top. There, he stood motionless,
thinking like the sand, as still as the desert.
Liet let the worm burrow itself into the ground and jumped away at the last moment, slogging through slumping powder sand, as if it were a swamp.


The last quotation seems similar to the dismounting procedure described in the original Dune novel (don't remember exactly but that's my recollection)

I dimly remember (but it's been many years) multiple places in the books where it is mentioned that they slow down (but never completely stop) the worms to get on and off. The movie is a movie, and they wanted things to look dramatic.

@Tom Yes, but except for the "pilot" - that's the most dangerous and thrilling part of the whole process. After that, the worm is under control of the rider, can slow down, go in circles etc.. Stilgar also notes in the book that Paul was too close to the worm on his first attempt due to his inexperience and the unexpected size of the Maker. The first one is also the one who doesn't climb on the worm - they're pulled up as the worm rotates to keep the vulnerable "scale" away from the sand, which is the basic mechanism of how the Fremen control the worms in the first place.

From the source novel there is this passage when Paul is taking him test

He glanced down at the hooks in his left hand, think­ing that he had only to shift those hooks down the curve of a maker’s im­mense side to make the crea­ture roll and turn, guid­ing it where he willed. He had seen it done. He had been helped up the side of a worm for a short ride in train­ing. The cap­tive worm could be rid­den un­til it lay ex­hausted and qui­es­cent upon the desert sur­face and a new maker must be sum­moned.

It seems logical that while the worm is on the surface and recovering, this would be a perfect time to board a group and supplies before setting off.

"It seems logical" - absolutely! Unfortunately, the question asks about it in the film/book, whose inhabitants appear to consider it a better idea to jump on a worm while it is at full speed and strength for some reason. Though it's possible they distinguish "show-off worms" on the one hand (mounted while moving by single people) and "transport worms" on the other (mounted by many people while at rest, next ride every 30 mins style).

There is no distinction in worms between "show-off" and "transport", they are just worms. Sure they have different sizes but that's all. There is nothing in either film or book about how they transport large groups at all. In fact, in the novel, Paul's test and the trip south are one event, not two separate ones.

Your conclusion here doesn't match the quote. When the worm is exhausted, a new one must be summoned. This explains how to get down from the old one, but not how to mount the new, non-exhausted worm.

IMO you are misreading/misinterpreting the quote. If you want to travel as fast as possible  obviously you must summon a new worm. But if you're transporting a large group you start off with a stationary worm. Anyway, it's not shown in the movie or described in the book so we're left with (imo) logical assumptions or flat out guesses...I guess.
